# Why does an ASP.NET TextBox.TextChanged not fire when the new text is blank?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a somewhat complicated setup for an ASP.NET TextBox. It is inside of a user control that's inside a repeater that's inside a repeater.

I am able to load text into the TextBox and also get TextChanged to fire when text is changed to anything EXCEPT FOR blank/empty. The event doesn't fire when the user clears out the TextBox.

Does anyone know why ASP.NET might discriminate between text and blank?

I made a simplified version of my problem to separate it from possible other factors. I get the same results.

Below is my aspx markup:

```
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptRepeat" EnableViewState="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:repeater runat="server" ID="rptChild" EnableViewState="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <uc:Things runat="server" ID="ucChild"></uc:Things>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:repeater>        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnBtn" Text="click"/>
```

Below is my user control markup

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtText"></asp:TextBox>
```

Below is the aspx code behind

```
    private List<List<TestObj>> data = null;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.rptRepeat.ItemCreated += rptRepeat_ItemCreated;
        this.rptRepeat.ItemDataBound += rptRepeat_ItemDataBound;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["data"] = data = new List<List<TestObj>>();

            for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                data.Add(new List<TestObj>());

                for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                {
                    data[0].Add(new TestObj
                    {
                        Text = x + "_" + y
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data = (List<List<TestObj>>)Session["data"];
        }

        this.rptRepeat.DataSource = data;
        this.rptRepeat.DataBind();
    }


    void rptRepeat_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var rptChild = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptChild");

        rptChild.ItemDataBound += rptChild_ItemDataBound;
    }

    void rptRepeat_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var rptChild = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptChild");
        var rowObj = (List<TestObj>)e.Item.DataItem;

        rptChild.DataSource = rowObj;
        rptChild.DataBind();
    }

    void rptChild_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var ucChild = (WebUserControl1)e.Item.FindControl("ucChild");
        var rowObj = (TestObj)e.Item.DataItem;

        ucChild.data = rowObj;
    }
```

Below is the user control code behind

```
    public TestObj data = null;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtText.TextChanged += txtText_TextChanged;
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtText.Text = data.Text;
    }

    void txtText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data.Text = this.txtText.Text;
    }
```

You can download the whole project at https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6zkqqsw71fvuyw/textchangetest.zip?dl=0 if you want to try tinkering with stuff to get me an answer.

The databinding of the repeater was intentionally put in Page_Load because otherwise child controls' events don't fire.

Comment: Adding some code would be helpful to answer

Comment: By having `AutoPostBack="true"` you tell the text box to fire a post back when the value is changed regardless of whether it's empty string or not. Show some code so we can help.

Comment: I am able to get it to work with blank text IF I move databinding to PreRender, store each user control's data object in session, and turn on viewstate. But I would still like to know why TextChanged doesn't fire for blank text without these changes.

Comment: Are you validating the text within ? if so you can use any validations to check whether blank

Comment: There's no validations going on.